# If a lambda function is used in one place but multiple times, should it be made local or global

Tags: c++, c++17

The criteria to delete an element from the vector is defined as a lambda function as its not used anywhere else. Now if delete_data is executed periodically, it must be creating new instances of lambda every time. How can we make its performance better:

1. Instead of defining criteria as lambda, defining it as inline function outside the delete_data().
2. By making lambda as static.
3. How can we inline block level lambda to improve performance?

   ```
    struct SomeStruct
    {
        string id;
        int psx;
        /*other data */
    }


    shared_mutex my_mutex;
    vector<SomeStruct>v;
    void delete_data(vector<SomeStruct>&v, string const& id)
    {
        auto const delete_criteria {[=](SomeStruct const& d){return (d.id == id);}};

        unique_lock ul{my_mutex};
        v.erase(find_if(begin(v), end(v), delete_criteria));
    }
   ```

Comment: Why do you think it'll be slower?

Comment: lambda instances are created at compile time. No incidence for execution time, especially after optimisation (-O3)

Comment: @Damien Do you mean delete_criteria will be created just once, despite the fact that its local to the function ?

Comment: @tzaman in kotlin there are options to inline, noinline etc. That made me feel that as delete_criteria is local, and we cant declare it inline inside function block, so it may be getting constructed as we enter scope and gets destroyed as we leave function scope multiple times.

Comment: My understanding is that after optimisation at compile time, everything useless is suppressed. You just get an optimised machine code for the *erase* function. With modern compilers, it is generally useless to enter in such code optimisation details

Comment: Neither of your first two options is going to produce correct results. An independent function won't let you compare against an argument to `delete_data` (`id`). If the lambda is static, then it will only be initialized once, on the first call to `delete_data`. So on subsequent calls that `id` argument isn't going to be used. This leaves only one option, so the question is mostly moot. You *have* to create a new functor object for each `id`. However, it doesn't automatically mean that is costly.

Comment: @virus00x That's not how C++ lambdas are implemented. It's essentially an anonymous class that gets compiled once just like the rest of your code; the compiler is already smart enough to inline the call if possible. Don't worry about micro-optimizations like this unless you've _measured_ that it's actually a bottleneck.

Comment: Note that `inline` these days has very little to do with inlining of function calls; it means that a function's definition can occur in multiple translation units.

Comment: My argument comes from experience with C++. Yours seems to be from a faulty test. Here's a proper test (https://wandbox.org/permlink/47W2i5CURhVB6keW). I also took the liberty of fixing a bug your example has.

Comment: _your second argument does not look correct._ It is correct. I made a [small sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47bab67f124d7f8f) to demonstrate. You may notice that it's always the `1` printed which was captured by value in the initialization in first call of `delete_data()`. Please, note that I didn't use a template. (There is a separate `static` instance for each distinct template instance which might have given you a false feeling.)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Please use your experience to improve my following faulty test: vector<int>v {1,2,3,4};
static auto is_odd{[](const auto n)  {if(1 == (n % 2)) cout << "odd \n"; else cout << "even \n";}};
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), is_odd);

Comment: It's a difference whether you capture by value or you provide an argument. Capturing happens when the lambda is instanced (once only for a static instance). In opposition, the arguments are passed on each individual call, of course. [extended small sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96db768adb2adaf4)

Comment: Thanks @Scheff . I got it. I forgot to remove= from [].

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  I understood my mistake.

Comment: Upvoting all the helpful comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two options are not correct, and the last option is not necessary. let us analyze them step by step.

> Instead of defining criteria as lambda, defining it as inline function outside the delete_data().

The third parameter of `find_if` is required to be a callable object which has only one parameter that accepts these elements in the range, that means, if you define a function, only one parameter of the element's type is permitted. you couldn't acquire `id` within that function you defined.

> By making lambda as static.

That will make a mistake. In other words, the value of `id` will never be changed within the lambda's compound-statement. Because of the following rules:

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration.

Simply speaking, the initialization for the object `delete_criteria` only be executed once. Reenters the function `delete_data`, the closure type object `delete_criteria` still remain the original value.  I.E, the value of `id` always be as same as that the function `delete_criteria` first executed. So, it's a bug to your program.

Well, Consider the last option in your question

> How can we inline block level lambda to improve performance?

No necessary. Because the function call operator of a closure type is public inline itselft, as said here.

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a **public inline function call operator** whose parameters and return type are described by the lambda-expression's parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively. For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call operator member template whose template-parameter-list consists of one invented type template-parameter for each occurrence of auto in the lambda's parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance.

I think what you only need to change here is that, change `=` in the lambda-expression to `&` or `&id`. This change will avoid the lambda-expression caputure the variable `id` by **copy**, conversely by reference.  This change will also make the closure type be a literal type. Even though the initialization for `delete_criteria` be evaluated every time the function `delete_data` enters, It does not cost too much for such an initialization.

Comment: well explained. Upvoting.